# this.props.data.map is getting undefined error

Tags: react-native

while executing the code

```
export default class Slides extends React.Component {
  renderSlides() {
    return this.props.data.map((slide)=> {
      return (
        <View key={slide.text}>
          <Text> {slide.text} </Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        style= {{ flex: 1 }}
      >
        { this.renderSlides() }
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

the error is [this.props.map() error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wcAH.png)

Comment: thats all and working but not working with my code. and I am passing an array so why the map function is not working?? Please help me out.

Comment: before map just check `this.props.data` is there or not like

`this.props.data && this.props.data.map(val => {})`

Comment: Where did you pass the data props to the Slides Component .can you show that code ?

Comment: sorry can you elaborate how do i check this.props.data without an return value or params

Comment: import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

import Slides from "../components/Slides";

const SLIDE_DATA = [
  { text: 'Welcome to JobApp' },
  { text: 'Use this to get a Job' },
  { text: 'Set your location, then swipe away' }  
]

export default class WelcomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Slides />
    );
  }
}

Comment: First you can comment the renderSlides function and you can put a alert (JSON.stringify(this.props.data)) inside of render and confrim the this.props.data is valid or not

Comment: i am getting alert of "undefined" @Prabhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to pass the data to Slides component

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
 import Slides from "../components/Slides";
 const SLIDE_DATA = [ { text: 'Welcome to JobApp' }, { text: 'Use this to get a Job' }, { text: 'Set your location, then swipe away' } ] 

 export default class WelcomeScreen extends React.Component {
   render() { 
      return(
          <Slides data = {SLIDE_DATA}/> 
      ); 
     } 
}
```

And you can get the data using this.props.data from Slides component